# Перебрать массив input's через цикл и получить их значение

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такой код:

```
<input class="field" type="number">
<input class="field" type="number">
<input class="field" type="number">
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<p>XXX<p>

(function() {
 let text = document.querySelector('p');
 let fields = document.querySelectorAll('.field');
 let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
 btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        text.textContent = fields[i].value;
        console.log(fields[i].value)
    }
 })
})()
```

Мне нужно записать в элемент `p` значения каждого `input's` при клике на кнопку. Но мой код почему то записывает значение только последнего поля, при этом в консоль выводит значения всех полей. В чем ошибка?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/962009/288409

Answer (score 3):

```js
(function() {
  let text = document.querySelector('p');
  let fields = document.querySelectorAll('.field');
  let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var newText = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
      newText += fields[i].value;
      console.log(fields[i].value);
    }
    text.textContent = newText;
  })
})();
```

```html
<input class="field" type="number" value="12" />
<input class="field" type="number" value="34" />
<input class="field" type="number" value="56" />
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<p>XXX</p>
```

Comment: Если бы Вы еще и обьяснили))

Comment: @RavenTheX Вы в цикле назначаете `text.textContent = fields[i].value;`. Естественно, в конце концов `text.textContent` будет равен левой части последнего присваивания.

Comment: @RavenTheX *Правой* части, конечно.

Comment: вот только по факту событые срабатывает для всех инпутов. И тепер когда я пытаюсь преобразовать значение к числу у меня еще и все `NaN` записываются

Comment: @RavenTheX По какому "факту"? Выражайтесь, пожалуйста, по-русски. Какое событие для инпутов? Событие у Вас в коде - для кнопки.