# Вывести значение из input в div и сохранять в список

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь решить задачу - нужно,чтобы значения, введенные в `input`, сохранялись и выводились в `div`.

```js
function copyText() {
  val = document.getElementById('inp1').value;
  document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = val;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="copyText();">Click me</button>
<input type="text" id="inp1" />
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Не могу разобраться как сделать так, чтобы старое значение не стиралось из `div` при введении нового значения и нажатии на клик, а сохранялось в див.То есть при введении нового значения в инпут и нажатии на клик, оно выводилось на следующей строке после предыдущего, (то есть добавлялось в список).

Comment: Не понятно, чего вы хотите добиться. *Не могу разобраться как сделать так,чтобы значение не стиралось из дива при обновлении страницы, а добавлялось в список.* Что за список?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор присваивания `=` *заменяет* имеющееся значение переменной/свойства новым.

Для *добавления* к значению, чаще всего применяется *оператор присваивания со сложением* **`+=`**.
Этот оператор равнозначен присваиванию переменной суммы ее значения с каким-либо другим. То есть, выражения вида `x += y;` и `x = x + y;` дадут одинаковый результат.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const inp = document.getElementById('inp1'),
        div = document.getElementById('div1'),
        btn = document.getElementById('btn1');
  btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (inp.value.length)   // добавляем текст только если его длина !== 0
      div.innerHTML += inp.value + '<br>'; 
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Click me</button>
<input type="text" id="inp1">
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

```js
function copyText() {
  var val = document.getElementById('inp1').value;
  var appendIt = document.createElement('span');
  appendIt.innerHTML = val;
  var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
  div1.appendChild(appendIt);
}
```

```css
#div1{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="copyText();">Click me</button>
<input type="text" id="inp1" />
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Почему минусуется рабочий ответ?

Comment: Потому, что вопрос был вообще о другом... Автор кардинально изменил вопрос... Заметил,  исправил свою ошибку...

Answer (score 1):

Просто нужно создать массив в глобальной области

```js
let strings = [];
function copyText() {
  val = document.getElementById('inp1').value;
  strings.push(val);
  document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = strings.join('\n');
}
```

```html
<button onClick="copyText();">Click me</button>
<input type="text" id="inp1" />
<div id="div1"></div>
```